# C++ library to build up execution pipeline

Tags: c++, pipeline

I have been searching for a re-usable execution pipeline library in C++ (job scheduler library?). I could not find anything within [Boost](http://boost.org). So I eventually found out two candidates:

- [google-concurrency-library](http://code.google.com/p/google-concurrency-library/wiki/PipelineExecutionFramework)
- [libpipeline](http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/)

Am I missing any other candidates ? Has anyone used them ? How good are they with regard to parallel io and multithreading ?
Those libraries still seems to be missing dependencies handling. For instance it does not seems clear to me how one would write something like:

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr P Q | head -3
```

In this very simple case, pipeline is walked bottom up, and the first `cat` stops executing when `head` process stops pulling.

However I do not see how I can benefit from multi-threading and or parallel io in case such as:

```
$ cat /raid1/file1 /raid2/file2 | tr P Q > /tmp/file3
```

There is no way for me to say: execute `tr` on 7 threads when 8 processors available.

Comment: I think you’re confusing something: pipelines don’t automatically mean that the *individual steps* in the pipeline are paralleliseable (as your example shows), it just means that all (or some) steps can be executed in parallel and poll / push data between themselves.

Comment: I would explore google concurrency lib further. It was just proposed to become part of the C++ standard. More here http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3534.html#Solution

Answer (score 3):

What are you looking for is a *dataflow* framework. Pipeline is a specialized form of dataflow, where all components have 1 consumer and 1 producer.

Boost supports dataflow, but unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar with Boost. Here's the link: http://dancinghacker.com/code/dataflow/dataflow/introduction/dataflow.html

Anyway, you should write your components as separate programs and use Unix pipes. Especially, if your data characteristic is (or can be easily transform into) lines/text.

Also an option is to write your own dataflow thing. It's not too hard, especially, when you have restrictions (I mean pipe: 1-consumer/1-producer), you should not implement a full dataflow framework. Piping is just about binding some kind of functions together, passing one's result into next one's arg. A dataflow framework is about a component interface/pattern and a bind technique. (It's fun, I've written one.)

Comment: boost::dataflow is a proposal that has not been accepted into boost.

Comment: Link broken: https://web.archive.org/web/20160605053459/http://dancinghacker.com/code/dataflow/dataflow/introduction/dataflow.html

Answer (score 2):

I would give Threading Building Blocks http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ a try.
It is open source and cross plattform. The Wikipedia article is pretty good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks

Answer (score 2):

I just read today about [RaftLib](http://raftlib.io), which uses templates and classes to create pipeline elements called "kernels". It allows for a serial pipeline like the Bash example you've shown, in addition to parallel dataflows. From the [Hello world example](https://gist.github.com/jonathan-beard/6a2fe1d9796cb7bb102cb8b34800fff1#file-hello_world-cpp) on the front page:

```
#include <raft>
#include <raftio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

class hi : public raft::kernel
{
public:
    hi() : raft::kernel()
    {
       output.addPort< std::string >( "0" ); 
    }

    virtual raft::kstatus run()
    {
        output[ "0" ].push( std::string( "Hello World\n" ) );
        return( raft::stop ); 
    }
};


int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    /** instantiate print kernel **/
    raft::print< std::string > p;
    /** instantiate hello world kernel **/
    hi hello;
    /** make a map object **/
    raft::map m;
    /** add kernels to map, both hello and p are executed concurrently **/
    m += hello >> p;
    /** execute the map **/
    m.exe();
    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```